# Jenkins Workflow Checkout Accessing BRANCH_NAME and GIT_COMMIT

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

I cannot seem to extract $GIT_COMMIT and $BRANCH_NAME from a Jenkins Workflow Checkout step.

I would like to be able to send this information through to my Gradle scripts in order to pass it onto external sources such as Static analysis etc.

Currently I try to run this:

```
checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '2b74a351-67d5-4d00-abd3-49842a984201', url: 'ssh://git@corporate.com:repo.git']]])
```

And I would like to achieve the following or something similar:

```
// Specified variables that can be reused
def branch = ${BRANCH_NAME}
def commit = ${GIT_COMMIT}
```

Or maybe this would work too:

```
print "BRANCH: ${BRANCH_NAME}, COMMIT: ${GIT_COMMIT}"
// or the following
print "BRANCH: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}, COMMIT: ${env.GIT_COMMIT}"
```

I did find the following issue which seems to be resolved but it doesn't work in version 1.15:

https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-30252

Anyone have any ideas how to workaround this or if there's a variable I cannot find?

Answer (score 47):

First of all,

```
def branch = ${BRANCH_NAME}
```

is not valid Groovy, or at least not doing what you think. Perhaps you meant

```
def branch = "${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

which would just be a silly way of writing

```
def branch = BRANCH_NAME
```

Anyway environment variables are not currently accessible directly as Groovy variables in Pipeline (there is a proposal to allow it); you need to use the `env` global variable:

```
def branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
```

From within an external process, such as a `sh` step, it is an actual environment variable, so

```
sh 'echo $BRANCH_NAME'
```

works (note that `'` means Groovy is *not* interpolating the variable).

Now, JENKINS-30252 was referring to multibranch projects. If you created a standalone Pipeline job, this variable will not be set.

Anyway in your case your `checkout` step is always checking out the `master` branch. If you actually have a multibranch project, then your `Jenkinsfile` should be using

```
checkout scm
```

which will check out a commit on the correct branch (always matching the revision of `Jenkinsfile` itself).

As to the commit hash, pending [JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100) this is not available automatically, but you can use something like

```
sh 'git rev-parse HEAD > commit'
def commit = readFile('commit').trim()
```

to access it.

Comment: Alright, so this helps me understand the problem better. There's a few things I don't know about Groovy as mentioned above but this helps me understand the differences of quotes as well. Interesting, I will try this out!

Comment: As to the last paragraph, see the [currently proposed syntax](https://github.com/abayer/workflow-scm-step-plugin/blob/39a28c8611c2c06e14d9e60b4a06366c57bfec18/src/main/resources/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/steps/scm/GenericSCMStep/help.html).

Comment: "environment variables are not currently accessible directly as Groovy variables" Do you have any supporting references for this from Jenkins source?

Comment: @JoeyStallmeyer He also states "you need to use the env global variable". So, the environment variable `BRANCH_NAME` can be accessed with this: `env.BRANCH_NAME` (as stated in the answer).

Answer (score 23):

I have two Jenkins instances.

In both instances, `GIT_COMMIT` and `BRANCH_NAME` environment variables are not defined.

When I try to get them from the return value of `checkout()` call, each instance behaves differently.

### Jenkins Instance 1

Jenkins version: 2.46.1

"Pipeline: SCM Step" plugin version: 2.5

Trying to access the environment variable as explained in the `checkout` [documentation](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-scm-step/#checkout-general-scm) fails.

```
def scmVars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '2b74a351-67d5-4d00-abd3-
    49842a984201', url: 'ssh://git@corporate.com:repo.git']]])
def commitHash = scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
```

`scmVars` returns NULL, and accessing `scmVars.GIT_BRANCH` fails with exception `java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'GIT_BRANCH' on null object`.

So I had to do the following in order to get the branch:

```
sh 'git name-rev --name-only HEAD > GIT_BRANCH'
sh 'cat GIT_BRANCH'
git_branch = readFile('GIT_BRANCH').trim()
env.GIT_BRANCH = git_branch
```

### Jenkins Instance 2

Jenkins version: 2.60.2

"Pipeline: SCM Step" plugin version: 2.6

In this instance, I could do the following with success:

```
def scmVars = checkout([$class: 'GitSCM', branches: [[name: '*/master']], 
    userRemoteConfigs: [[credentialsId: '2b74a351-67d5-4d00-abd3-
    49842a984201', url: 'ssh://git@corporate.com:repo.git']]])
env.GIT_COMMIT = scmVars.GIT_COMMIT
env.GIT_BRANCH = scmVars.GIT_BRANCH
```

So please check which approach works for your Jenkins instance and use it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed explanation on failure regarding versions. 

I can confirm that for Jenkins Instance 2 with "Pipeline: SCM Step" plugin version: 2.5 also fails on your second explanation.

On version  2.73.3 of Jenkins, so it's definitely an error on the plugin on versions below 2.6, updating it solved this

Comment: @Antony Thanks a lot for this answer you have almost saved my job!!. The second approach worked for me!. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to access the `BRANCH_NAME` from Jenkins environment variable as a shell script, use the below snippet.

`sh 'echo Branch Name: $BRANCH_NAME'`

The response should be as below:

`Branch Name: the_checkedout_branch`