# Not able to read Git Environment variables Jenkins using Groovy Jenkinsfile

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

The Git Plugin is installed (by default) in my Jenkins but I'm unable to get the env variables that are supposed to be passed in by the Git Plugin. I'm looking for:

```
GIT_COMMIT
GIT_BRANCH
GIT_PREVIOUS_COMMIT 
GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT
GIT_URL
```

etc.  I'm using the Pipeline Job Item that's pointing at a Github repo with the Jenkinsfile with the following code

```
stage 'PushToProd'
node {
    git url: "https://github.com/username/fakeurl.git"
    echo "Starting PushToProd"
    sh 'printenv'
    sh 'env'
    sh 'echo $BRANCH_NAME' 
    sh 'echo $GIT_COMMIT'
}
```

I'm getting plenty of environment variables when I use `env` or `printenv` just not the Github plugin ones.
Any tips on how I can get the Git env variables passed in to the job?

**Update**: I'm able to easily get the Git env variables when I use a Freestyle Project and have a shell step use `echo $GIT_COMMIT`.  Still want to know though how to get it to work using Jenkinsfile + Pipeline job item.

Comment: You can access env variables in Jenkinsfile using `env.VARIABLE`. I remember that `env.BRANCH_NAME` works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Workflow Checkout Accessing BRANCH\_NAME and GIT\_COMMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304208/jenkins-workflow-checkout-accessing-branch-name-and-git-commit)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This won't work due to lack of double quotes, missing curly braces, and missing `env.`:

```
sh 'echo $BRANCH_NAME'
```

This works as expected in a Jenkinsfile:

```
node {
    sh "echo ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
}
```

Comment: Hey @Konrad Kleine, I am having the same issue and the printenv is not even printing the git env variables within pipeline. Do you have any hint on this?

Comment: Hey @TibinPaul, no I have no hints for you and stopped using Jenkins Pipeline.

Answer (score 5):

So, anyone else who has stumbled onto this Stackoverflow issue should be aware that this is a *bug* with the current pipeline situation.

Lots of discussion here: https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-35230

Essentially the plugin is not able to correctly add environment variables due to some incompatibilities with pipeline.

Comment: Above issue duplicates https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100 - which is now FIXED! :-) Git plugin 3.3.1 has been released with the necessary pull request merged.

Comment: WOO!! Thanks Morgan!

Comment: Actually, if you're using the generic `checkout scm` this does not work.

Answer (score 3):

This is fixed in [Git plugin 3.3.1](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Git+Plugin#GitPlugin-Version3.3.1(Jun23,2017))

Version 3.3.1 (Jun 23, 2017)

- Print first line of commit message in console log (JENKINS-38241)
- **Allow scm steps to return revision ([JENKINS-26100](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-26100))**
- Don't require crumb for POST to /git/notifyCommit even when CSRF is enabled (JENKINS-34350)
- Fix credentials tracking null pointer exception in pipeline library use (JENKINS-44640)
- Fix credentials tracking null pointer exception in git parameters use (JENKINS-44087)

Comment: Also needs latest Jenkins. It's still not working maybe the workplace cps plugin needs to release too...

Answer (score 2):

Most of the pipeline examples I've found wrap the code in a "node" closure, which for some reason doesn't allow the Jenkins Git plugin to populate the environment variables.

However, if instead you wrap it like this, the environment variables are set properly:

```
pipeline {
  agent {
    label ('<AGENT>')
  }
  stages {
    stage('<STAGE>') {
      steps {
        <CODE>
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm not sure which closures are crucial here, but this formatting allowed me to access env variables such as `env.GIT_COMMIT`

Answer (score 1):

You may need to do something like this.

```
node {
   def branch = env.BRANCH_NAME
   sh "My branch name: ${branch}"
}
```