# How to write out environment variable with Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

How can I write out environment variable(s) with `writeFile` in Jenkins pipelines?
It seems such an easy task but I can't find any documentation on how to get it to work.

I tried `$VAR`, `${VAR}` and `${env.VAR}`, nothing works...?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a declarative pipeline (using a scripted block for `writeFile`) it will look like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    environment {
        SENTENCE = 'Hello World\n'
    }

    stages {
        stage('Write') {
            steps {
                script {
                    writeFile file: 'script.txt', text: env.SENTENCE
                }
            }
        }
        
        stage('Verify') {
            steps {
                sh 'cat script.txt'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
...
[Pipeline] { (Verify)
[Pipeline] sh
[test] Running shell script
+ cat script.txt
Hello World
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

If you want to avoid groovy, this will work too:

```
writeFile file: 'script.txt', text: "${SENTENCE}"
```

To combine your env var with text you can do:

```
...
environment {
    SENTENCE = 'Hello World'
}
...

writeFile file: 'script.txt', text: env.SENTENCE + ' is my newest sentence!\n'
```

Comment: How would I combine variables with literal text?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Updated the answer

Comment: I'm not sure we should discuss here, but I get a Nullpointer exception now at this line:

https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/stable-2.89/core/src/main/java/hudson/FilePath.java#L1923

Comment: @FlorianPeschka Can you share your pipeline (or the part where it fails) + you are using the latest version of the plugin?

Comment: It appears `env.GIT_COMMIT` (what I want to write) is `null`. I suspect thats a different issue with my pipeline though.

Comment: The env var of GIT_COMMIT is only set when you use the git plugin. BUT for pipelines this behaviour is a bit different. You really have to define the use as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46317774/jenkins-git-environment-variables-not-set-in-pipeline