# Bitbucket Tagging for every bitbucket commit

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines

Need help for creating tag for every bit bucket commit.

Please let me know if anyone have implemented this using Jenkins pipeline, if yes how can we achieve that

Comment: Hey, why do you want to create a tag for every commit? What's the use case?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume you have some sort of Multi-branch pipeline job set up, or some mechanism to trigger a jenkins job for each commit to BitBucket. Bitbucket will need to trigger a Jenkins job for [each commit](https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/manage-webhooks/) via a [webhook](https://plugins.jenkins.io/bitbucket/)

In your pipeline code, you'll need to do the following:

1. Get the hash of your commit. You can get this data from the GIT_COMMIT variable in the [Git Jenkins Plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/git/#commit-variables)
2. Create a Bitbucket tag via their [api](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/repositories/%7Bworkspace%7D/%7Brepo_slug%7D/refs/tags#post) with the commit hash mentioned above

```
curl https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/repositories/jdoe/myrepo/refs/tags \
-s -u jdoe -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
    "name" : "new-tag-name",
    "target" : {
        "hash" : "a1b2c3d4e5f6",
    }
}'
```

There are few different ways to do #2.

- Put that code in a powershell script and run it from your job.
- Call it directly from your jenkins pipeline [like this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42662243/17128827).
- Or if you plan to do this from many jobs, you could also create your own Bitbucket Api Client [shared library](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/) that does the api interaction for you.

Note: You'll likely need to [authenticate](https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/meta/authentication) these Bitbucket api requests

Comment: Thank You for response. I tried below pipeline and it is not working, please let me know if something is wrong.  stage("Git Tagging"){
        steps{ withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'SCM_Credential_ID', variable: 'USERPASS')]){
          sh ''' curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -s -u $USERPASS -i 'https://<Bitbucketrepourl>/refs/tags' --data '{
          "name": "Test-Tag",
          "target":{
          "hash": "<commit ID>"
    // "hash": "$(GIT_COMMIT)" did not work
           }
          }'
        ''' }}}

Comment: Did the Bitbucket api give you an error message?

Comment: It dosent recognize GIT_COMMIT

Comment: I think you might need an 'env.' in front of GIT_COMMIT ("$(env.GIT_COMMIT)"). Per https://stackoverflow.com/a/38657848/17128827.

Comment: Issue is resolved with env.GIT_COMMIT

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get rid of error using env.GIT_COMMIT