# Jenkins Pipeline accessing environment variables

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to use DSL pipelines in Jenkins. I thought it'd be nice if I could use the project name as part of my script.

```
git credentialsId: 'ffffffff-ffff-ffff-ffff-ffffffffffffff',\
url: "${repo_root}/${JOB_NAME}.git"
```

I get the error:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: \
No such property: JOB_NAME for class: groovy.lang.Binding
```

I thought I followed [these directions](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/User-Power-Moves#user-content-access-the-jenkins-environment-variables), and they mention `JOB_NAME` as one of the variables.

I decided to try:

```
sh 'env'
```

in my DSL, and this prints out:

```
JOB_NAME = foo-bar
```

which is what I expect.

Another [blog mentions](http://codeventor.blogspot.com/2015/07/jenkins-dsl-scripting-part-3.html):

> **Usage of environment variables**
>   We have two ways to get their value. The properties passed by `-D=` during the startup we could read as `System.getProperty("key")` thanks to the Groovy's strong relation with Java.
>
> Reading normal environment variables in Java way is the `System.getenv("VARIABLE")`...

Let's try this:

```
println "JOB_NAME = " + System.getenv('JOB_NAME');
```

Now, I get:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'System' on null object
```

Null object? But, I can see that `JOB_NAME` is an environment variable!

How do I read in the `$JOB_NAME` into a DSL script in a Pipeline job. I am trying a Pipeline job, and when I get that working will make this a Multibranch Pipeline with a `Jenkinsfile`.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

All environment variables are accessible using `env`, e.g. `${env.JOB_NAME}`.

Comment: That works. `JOB_NAME` was mentioned as a special Jenkins variable that suppose to be already defined.

Answer (score 15):

Okay this really vexed me for a while today. Ultimately, I was being done in by a couple of things:

- Single-quoted strings in Groovy mean "don't evaluate variables," just like it does in bash
- Using $ interpolation is completely unnecessary if you're just referencing the variable, so you can just do `env.JOB_NAME`.

This SO question proved to be the one that helped me crack the code: [Jenkins Workflow Checkout Accessing BRANCH_NAME and GIT_COMMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304208/jenkins-workflow-checkout-accessing-branch-name-and-git-commit)

Answer (score 6):

Indeed just use `${env.JOB_NAME}` to access a known variable.

However if you need to access environment variable where name is given by another variable (dynamic access), just use `env["your-env-variable"]`.

I had the problem where I configured 3 environment variables (in `Jenkins -> Administer -> Configure System -> Environment variables`), let's name them `ENV_VAR_1`, `ENV_VAR_2`, `ENV_VAR_3`.
Now I want to dynamically access them, I can do as such :

```
def envVarName = "ENV_VAR_" + count  // Suppose count is initialized in a loop somewhere above...

def value = env[envVarName]  // Will be resolved to env["ENV_VAR_1"] depending on count value
```

My environment variables in Jenkins configuration look like this :

[image]

Comment: This does not work, just tested it. Please give more details @Pom12.

Comment: I'm currently using it succesfully for system defined environment variables, as I show in my edited post. What version of Jenkins are you using ?

Comment: It also allows setting the variables directly with `env[var]`.

Comment: I can confirm this worked with Jenkins ver. 2.46.1.
Jenkins > Manage Jenkins > Configure System > Global properties > Environment variables.

`name=COMMON_AUTOMATION_GIT_REPO`
`value=c:/jenkins_local/shared_workspace/CommonAutomationGitRepo`

Then within my groovy pipeline script:

`      def commonRepo = env["COMMON_AUTOMATION_GIT_REPO"];`
`      echo "Using common repo: ${commonRepo}"`

which resulted in the output:

`[Pipeline] echo`
`Using common repo: c:/jenkins_local/shared_workspace/CommonAutomationGitRepo`

Comment: This worked for me ```env["$variable"]```

Answer (score 1):

I had an issue with this not working. The globally set properties/environment variables were only available inside a `node` step. It's a bug in version 2.4 of Pipeline plugin. Upgrade to 2.5 if you face this issue and your global properties will be available anywhere in the script. I've posted this to the Jenkins wiki [here](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28921?focusedCommentId=300882&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-300882) with the test script I used.