# Accessing environment variables from Groovy scripts

Tags: groovy, environment-variables

I have to access an environment variable from my Groovy script. I am not using Jenkins. How do I get the variable?

Comment: Have you tried https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21236268/access-to-build-environment-variables-from-a-groovy-script-in-a-jenkins-build-st?  Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40215394/how-to-get-environment-variable-in-jenkins-groovy-script-console Have you tried: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38599641/jenkins-pipeline-accessing-environment-variables ...  What _have_ you tried?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [java.lang.System#getenv(java.lang.String)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv(java.lang.String))

Example:

```
def envVar = System.getenv('my_env_var')
```

Answer (score 2):

A shorter groovy way would be like this:

```java
def envVar = System.env['my_env_var']
```

Here is an [example](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&codez=eJxLSU1TSM0rC0ssUrBVCK4sLknN1QPyo9UDHEM81GO5Cooy80o0ICo0ubgUkAAARg8Q_A).