# Capturing shell script output from Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: git, shell, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to extract git branch and commit information in my Jenkinsfile as following:

```
def commit = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
def branch = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
```

I am trying to print it afterwards like this:

```
println("Branch: ${branch}, Commit: ${commit}")
```

Instead of getting real values, I am left with this:

```
Branch: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator@545511bf, Commit: org.jenkinsci.plugins.pipeline.modeldefinition.ClosureModelTranslator@545511bf
```

Am I doing something wrong and how can I retrieve values I need properly?

Edit: No, the suggested duplicate is not an answer, because I am aware of the shell commands used to retrieve the info I need. My Problem is the way that info is being delivered to me, as a `ClosureModelTranslator` instead of a `String`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins Workflow Checkout Accessing BRANCH\_NAME and GIT\_COMMIT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36304208/jenkins-workflow-checkout-accessing-branch-name-and-git-commit)

Comment: If you cared to read the post you claim to be a duplicate of, you would have actually noticed it is NOT a duplicate @KevinBurnett

Comment: i was trying to be helpful. does the answer to that question not help you get the branch and commit information?

Comment: My problem is of a different kind, as you might have noticed. I am indeed trying what is suggested in that thread, but the result I'm getting is of a different type than it should have been.

Comment: do you get the same bad result if you do `sh 'git rev-parse HEAD > commit'; def commit = readFile('commit').trim()` ?

Comment: What you are referring to is a hack being used before 'returnStdout' was implemented. I would rather not create and read unnecessary files on my disk just to get a commit. My question is targeted at a specific method, not workarounds that were used before. I understand you're trying to be helpful, but unfortunately, you are not.

Comment: And yes, to answer your question, the result is the same as in my problem.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

does this full pipeline work for you? working for me with Pipeline plugin 2.4.

```
pipeline {
  agent { label 'docker' }
  stages {
    stage("test_capture_output_and_print") {
      steps {
        script {
          def commitSha = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse HEAD').trim()
          println("commitSha: ${commitSha}")
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. My mistake was trying to access those values outside the script closure.