# Using git commit id and tag as Jenkins build parameters

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When creating a build pipeline, is there is a way to get the git commit id and tag and consume them as build parameters when jenkins checks out a polled git repo?

Comment: You can use a bash execution and run something like `git log -1 --pretty="%H"` to get the commit hash. You can then use this elsewhere.

Comment: indeed. there are some further details and links over at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43738237/capturing-shell-script-output-from-jenkins-pipeline/43739276#43739276

Comment: Thanks that works for the commit id but what about the tag? Right now I have git tag | tail -1 but that only makes sense if the commit is actually tagged... otherwise I'll just pick up the last tag. What can I do to make sure I pick up a tag that should correlate with the commit id?

Comment: How about [git describe](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-describe)?

Comment: Does not seem to work:
~/chef-repo/cookbooks/base - - master - git describe
fatal: No annotated tags can describe '90cc3dfebb14e9b8b42f68c3461793c0f90133bc'.
However, there were unannotated tags: try --tags.
 ✘  ~/chef-repo/cookbooks/base - - master - git describe --tags
v2.1.49