# Jenkins pipeline branch name returns null

Tags: git, jenkins, groovy

I'm trying to get the name of my branch for a jenkins groovy script. I cannot get the current branch name. I try the following:

```
stage('Check out code')
checkout scm
echo "My branch is: ${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
```

Here is the output - it always returns null.

```
 Checking out Revision 33b531b2f1caaf8b64d968e437306f39d2dba1da   (origin/pipeline)
  > git.exe config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
  > git.exe checkout -f 33b531b2f1caaf8b64d968e437306f39d2dba1da
 [Pipeline] echo
 My branch is: null
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: Tried: `echo "My branch is: ${BRANCH_NAME}"`?

Comment: @tim_yates tried that with the same result

Comment: Het @pogorman - have you managed to get it worked? I am having the same issue (using normal pipeline)!

Comment: This variable only works in a multibranch pipeline - see the answer below. I am only using multibranch pipelines now

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This variable only works in a multibranch pipline:

BRANCH_NAME
    For a multibranch project, this will be set to the name of the branch being built, for example in case you wish to deploy to production from master but not from feature branches.

I was testing in a normal pipline

Answer (score 9):

In Jenkins there is two pipeline options:

1. New Item -> Pipeline --> `env.BRANCH_NAME` return branch `null`
2. New Item -> Multibranch Pipeline --> `env.BRANCH_NAME` return branch `master or branch name`

Answer (score 7):

In the pipeline job I'm using `env.GIT_BRANCH` which resolves to `origin/{BRANCH}`

In the case of a multibranch job, `env.GIT_BRANCH` resolves to `{BRANCH}` (no `origin/`).

Answer (score 6):

```
git.exe checkout -f 33b531b2f1caaf8b64d968e437306f39d2dba1da
```

That would make the git repo enter a [**detached HEAD** mode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3965714/6309), which, by its very nature, has no branch.

From [Jenkinsfile](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/):

> The checkout step will checkout code from source control; `scm` is a special variable which instructs the checkout step to clone the specific revision which triggered this Pipeline run.

So the `${env.BRANCH_NAME}` is null.

As mentioned in "[Jenkins Workflow Checkout Accessing BRANCH_NAME and GIT_COMMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36332154/6309)", you can get the SHA1 you just checked out with the groovy syntax (to be adapted in a Jenkins pipeline DSL):

```
sh 'git rev-parse HEAD > commit'
def commit = readFile('commit').trim()
```

Comment: That means you could then try to guess which branch is involved from the checked out SHA1: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1419637/6309

Answer (score 6):

My workaround, Don't know if work for someone else..

```
def branchName = getCurrentBranch()
echo 'My branch is' + branchName

def getCurrentBranch () {
    return sh (
        script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD',
        returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
}
```

Comment: For me, that returns `HEAD` which is not helpful :(

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue, but I resolved it by changing

```
println "${env.BRANCH_NAME}"
```

to

```
println "${BRANCH_NAME}"
```

Note my plugin is also checking out in detached mode:

```
git checkout -f e10a170e17fb5f9282f903a7b3cd17bd2e181dee
```

Answer (score 0):

From a simple pipeline you can use the following script:

```
\\...
stage('Test') {
        steps {
            script {
                branchName = sh(label: 'getBranchName', returnStdout: true, script: 'git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD').trim()
                println branchName
            }   
        }
      } 
\\...
```

Answer (score 0):

this code worked for me.

```
def BRANCH_NAME = getCurrentBranch()
echo 'Current branch is' + BRANCH_NAME
def getCurrentBranch () {
    return sh (
    script: 'git name-rev --name-only HEAD',
    returnStdout: true
    ).trim()
}
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31989005)

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me:

```
env.BRANCH_NAME = scm.branches[0].name
```

I have found this answer on [Get git branch name in Jenkins Pipeline/Jenkinsfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42383273/get-git-branch-name-in-jenkins-pipeline-jenkinsfile).