# How to catch branch name in Jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins for CI-CD on docker environment.
I have 3 environments and branches according to the environment. 
Say, **develop**, **qa**, **prod**.

I am using Jenkins pipeline for building and pushing the image to DTR.

I just want to check how can I get the branch name in jenkinsfile so that I can have a condition on the basis of branch name to push the Docker image dependent upon branch name like:

```
if(env.BRANCH_NAME==develop){
```

Below is my Jenkinsfile:

```
pipeline {
    agent {
       label "master"
    }

    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Jar..........................'
                echo 'Pulling................................................' + env.BRANCH_NAME
                sh 'npm install'

            }
        }
        stage('Build-Image') {
            steps {
                echo '..........................Building Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker build -t some_org_dev/some_repo:v0.1 --build-arg PORT=9007 --build-arg ENVIRONMENT=develop .'
            }
        }
        stage('Tag-Image') {
            steps {

            if(env.BRANCH_NAME==develop){
                echo '..........................Taging Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker login some_org_dev/some_repo -u username -p password'
                sh 'sudo docker tag some_org_dev/some_repo:v0.1 some_org/some_repo/service-portal:v0.1'
                }else if(env.BRANCH_NAME==qa){
                echo '..........................Taging Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker login some_org_qa/some_repo -u username -p password'
                sh 'sudo docker tag some_org_qa/some_repo:v0.1 some_org/some_repo/service-portal:v0.1'

            }
        }
        stage('Push-Image') {
            steps {
            if(env.BRANCH_NAME==develop){
                echo '..........................Pushing Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker push some_org_dev/some_repo:v0.1 some_org/some_repo/service-portal:v0.1'
                }
            }else if(env.BRANCH_NAME==qa){
                echo '..........................Pushing Image..........................'
                sh 'sudo docker push some_org_qa/some_repo:v0.1 some_org/some_repo/service-portal:v0.1'

            }

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you are missing quotes, Is the error your getting an undefined var?
Try:

```
if (env.BRANCH_NAME== 'develop') {\\code here}
```

Comment: I am getting **null** at `echo 'Pulling................................................' + env.BRANCH_NAME` in **stage('Build') {**

Comment: could you try `echo('Pulling................................................' + env.BRANCH_NAME)` for me

Comment: Same problem is here. . getting null

Comment: Have you done `checkout scm`? if not can you try above this command?

Comment: I have added `checkout scm` but still i am getting null. On the other hand if I do  `echo 'Pulling Job name......' + env.JOB_NAME` I am getting the name of the job but branch is still null

Comment: Ah it appears this is only available in a multi-branch pipeline,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43770058/jenkins-pipeline-branch-name-returns-null are you using a multi-branch pipeline?

Comment: No I am using pipeline

Comment: This appears to be why. You could swap to multi-branch pipeline, this would give you a job per branch. And your jenkinsfile would still function as is.

Answer (score 2):

On a multibranch-pipeline, I'm using something like the following:

```
pipeline {
  agent { label "jenkins" }

  stages {
    stage("A Stage") {
      when {
        expression { GIT_BRANCH ==~ /(develop)/ }
      }

      steps {
        sh 'deploy'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

You might need to poke around with `sh 'env'` if you aren't using multibranch.